# How do i not override an array when i iterate on it the second time

Tags: java, arrays

How can I make the second iteration use the first array "poqet" to switch their positions from true to false, but without changing their state when the first iteration made them all true?

```
public class Dhoma {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean poqet[] = new boolean[100];
        int njerezit[] = new int[100];
        int count = 0;
        int nrRendorP = 0;
        int nrRendorN = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < njerezit.length; i++) {
            nrRendorN++;            
            for (int k = 0; k < poqet.length; k++) {
                nrRendorP++;
                if (nrRendorP == 100) {
                    nrRendorP = 0;
                }

                poqet[i] = Switch(nrRendorN, nrRendorP);

                System.out.println(k + " " + poqet[i]);
            }
        }
        // System.out.println("Jane te ndezura "+ count);
    }

    private static boolean Switch(int nr, int n) {
        if (n % nr == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that `if(poqet[i] = true)` isn't really what you wanted to do. That's *setting* `poqet[i]` to true, for *every* element it looks at. If that was really intentional, why use an `if` at all? That condition will *always* evaluate to `true`.

Comment: (It would help if you could explain what you're trying to achieve. Your first `for` loop looks very odd to me.)

Comment: the problem is if there are 100 light bulbs and the first iteration turns all of them on, the second person should turn only (2,4,6...) the third person(3,6,9...) and so on. But when the loop ends there should be 10 light bulbs true, and in my code there is only one true in the end.

Comment: So which loop is meant to be which? Rather than two loops, I'd expect you to have one outer loop and one inner loop (and maybe another to display the results at the end). I suspect you *do* want each iteration of the array to affect everything in the array. (It's unclear what the purpose of `njerezit` is as well, by the way.) I suggest you take a step back and potentially rewrite the code from scratch, checking it as you go with pencil and paper.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have one outer and one inner loop it just messed it up a little bit writing it here, consider that the first loop is the outer one and the second is the inner one. The 'njerezit' array i thought it would be useful to represent the people that are going to change the bulbs(poqet) state. i edited my post that is how it currently looks.

Comment: @ErmalRatkoceri I still don't understand your goal here. When you say the second person should turn only (2, 4, 6...) does that mean he turns them off? And the third person would then turn lamps that are off on and lamps are on off? Or are you really just looking what the array looks like when only 10 are turned on? The latter seems unlikely as you would not need any loop for that at all (every 10th would be turned on)

Comment: "it just messed it up a little bit writing it here" - do you mean that wasn't your actual code before? Is it your actual code now? Next, please think about what you're trying to achieve with your `Switch` method. Is it trying to tell you "the new value of the array element" or "whether the element's value should be toggled between true and false"? At the moment, you're ignoring the current value...

Comment: @Mark by my question i mean the second person only switches the bulbs that are factors of number 2. No matter what the state of the bulbs is every person that goes in switches them and in the end when the 100th person goes in and switches the last bulb i am supposed to get how many bulbs were on when the last person goes out of the loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet with the Switch method i tried to toggle the elemets value between true and false. it is my code but i was trying various stuff and when i copied it and pasted it here i didnt see that i had messed up the brackets.

Comment: Your Switch method *can't* toggle values in the array - because nothing in the method depends on the current value of the array. You could use it as a "should I toggle" method, and use `poqet[i] = poqet[i] ^ Switch(nrRendorN, nrRendorP);` though.

Comment: @ErmalRatkoceri okay but then why the `but without changing their state` in your question? It seems to me like you very much want to change their state...  otherwise what's the point?

Comment: @JonSkeet if there is a way to do the value toggle without the method it would be useful too, i am just a new student in java programming and just got into arrays so i am trying to figure out what im doing in that code. If you could explain my code to me i would be grateful. i know it sounds a little weird but id appreciate it

Comment: @Mark man you get the point what im trying to achieve. what i meant to say is i dont want the values to re set to false when the second iteration starts.

Comment: @ErmalRatkoceri see I didn't get that at all because that is not what's happening in your code anyway or what would happen unless you explicitly did something to make it happen. So it's good we talked about this ;) It's actually your Switch method (well technically the line that calls it) that sets your values to false, there is no reset happening

Comment: To avoid the method, you'd just use an `if` statement in your loop: `if (nrRendorP % nrRendorN == 0) { poquet[i] = !poquet[i]; }`

Comment: @Mark so how can i re-write that method so it wont be setting my values to false but keeping the current value that it has from the last iteration.

Comment: @JonSkeet the result with using that if (nrRendorP % nrRendorN == 0) {poqet[i] = !poqet[i];} is still the same. Right now my brain just left.

Comment: It really shouldn't be - but you may have made other changes I'm not aware of. Unfortunately, this sort of "interactive debugging" session isn't the way Stack Overflow works. I would *strongly* advise you to step through your code with a debugger and a piece of paper, and consider what you *expect* to happen at each step vs what actually happens. I'd start off with a much smaller number of elements - 20, say - so you can easily see the result of each larger step.